# How implement different partitioning in spark?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, partitioning

There is a dataframew with columns: `date` and `error`. A partitioning for data should be the like `yyyy-dd-mm` but all columns with error should be written into different location. Is there a way to add custom partition resolving which generate path to `date` with one algorithm and different for `error`? In ideal way soldering structure should be like that:

```
my_table/data/date=2022-01-01/
my_table/error/
```

Any ideas?

P.S. Why custom partition? Yes I can add filter and the write twice - but this leads to twice reading. Using partition "hacking" (in theory) allows to read one and write once.

Answer (score 0):

If possible you can cache the dataframe first and then filter and write twice so you will avoid reading the data twice.

Otherwise, without writing a new partitioner, you can add a new column using [case when](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#when) which maps each valid date to itself and each error to a NULL value and then use the standard partitionBy method in Spark.
The NULL values will be saved under a partition called  `__HIVE_DEFAULT_PARTITION__`